# WebP Conversion from Jpeg same as PNG?

Tags: webp

If I have PNG files that are more photorealistic in nature, and probably should have been Jpegs, will conversion from PNG to WebP result in a similar result as if the files had been Jpeg and converted to WebP? Is it the content of the images that affect the conversion, or the settings of the actual image file? For instance, if the PNG was saved with transparency, but there are no transparent areas of the image, will the conversion be smart enough to recognize that?

Comment: You opening line makes no sense - *"probably should have been Jpegs"* is illogical. What makes you think this? PNG is lossless so in theory will invariably be better than jpg, the resulting conversion will be dependant on this & whether you convert to WebP lossy or lossless. Whether transparency is also converted will depend on how smart the particular converter is.

Comment: I think this is a fair question (because I think I have it too). I also have a few PNGs on a website that are photorealistic, don't have any transparency in them, and don't need to be shown in super high res. In other words, they are prime candidates to be JPGs because the file size of JPGs is smaller for such images. I'm curious to know if (in general) when a large file size PNG or a smaller filesize of the same image JPG will result in a similar-sized WEBP after conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two questions. The comment of Tetsujin includes implicitely all the answers.

If you want the best quality, go for a conversion from PNG (lossless) to WebP (losseless). (Jpeg is always lossy by design, so, they could not be compared at this stage.)
WebP lossless (VP8L encoding) handles transparency, as a decent conversion tool should do it as well.